# Automating Nightly Build Installation?

Tags: windows, installation, automation, updates

Every night a new build of my program is made and copied to a /Builds/ folder. I have a Windows machine that I want to have uninstall the program then install the latest version of the program from the /Builds/ folder.

Currently the build results in two separate setup.exe files which are InstallShield installation wizard executables. I want this to happen every night after the build finishes:

- Uninstall first component.
- Uninstall second component.
- Install newest build of first component using setup.exe.
- Install newest build of second component using setup.exe.

I figured that there probably already exists a software solution for automating installations like this. Are there any software solutions out there than can do what I need? Preferrably for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some complex and highly capable deployment suites available but that may be overkill for what you need.

A very easy to implement and free solution uses batch scripts and Scheduled Tasks. To make it happen you'll need that new build to support silent installs and silent uninstalls.  With the silent (un)installs, you can setup a little batch script that goes through the four steps you outlines. As a bonus to your customers, if the same install package will uninstall an older version then that will make your script easier.

Make sure that the batch script checks to make sure that the build files available are actually the latest builds.  You don't want to install yesterday's build and not know about it. With your batch script have that batch script run as a Scheduled Tasks at a time far enough away from the build will finish so you'll be sure that the build has completed.

Comment: How do I use batch scripts with InstallShield wizards? There are certain installation settings/variables that need to be set, it's not just clicking Next, Next, Next, Install, Finish.

Comment: In a batch script you would call your setup.exe with a series of command line options that specify an answer files, whether to run in silent mode or not. You'll need to check the documentation on your version of InstallShield to see what options are available and how configuration answers should be passed to the installer.